# Equivalence of zero divisor in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $x$ be a nonzero element in a commutative ring, then $\exists y\neq0(xy=0)$ ($x$ is a zero divisor) iff $\exists y\neq 0(x^2y=0)$. $(\rightarrow)$ part is pretty trivial. How to prove the other way?

Comment: $x^2y = x(xy)$. If $xy = 0$ then you are still done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $x^2y=x(xy)$. Consider the cases $xy = 0$ and $xy \ne 0$.